# Using dropdown filter to dynamic update Highchart

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

currently I was trying to add a dropdown filter button on my chart to let users select a specific values from a data attribute and filter the related data shown on the chart.

I populated my data's attribute to the select unit, and I was trying to update the chart with parse the data from the selective value, but seems the data didn't update on the HighChart.

Here is my code:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dontooleng/ng86f07L/38/)

```
const data = [
{
    "Data": "aaa",
    "Media": "1",
    "Row": "1",
    "Column": "3",
    "Code": "24",
},
{
    "Data": "aaa",
    "Media": "2",
    "Row": "1",
    "Column": "1",
    "Code": "24",
},
{
    "Data": "aaa",
    "Media": "3",
    "Row": "1",
    "Column": "3",
    "Code": "24",
},
{
    "Data": "aaa",
    "Media": "4",
    "Row": "1",
    "Column": "2",
    "Code": "24",
},
{
    "Data": "aaa",
    "Media": "1",
    "Row": "2",
    "Column": "1",
    "Code": "24",
},

    // populate Media to dropdown list
$.each(data, function (index, record) {
    $('<option>', {
        value: record.Media,
        text: record.Media
    }).appendTo("#select_media");
});

// remove duplicate value from dropdown list
var optionValues =[];
$('#select_media option').each(function(){
if($.inArray(this.value, optionValues) >-1){
    $(this).remove()
}else{
    optionValues.push(this.value);
}
});

// getting drop down list value
var mediaselect = document.getElementById("select_media").value


mediaselect_str = String(mediaselect)

const parsedData = []
data.forEach(obj => {
    if (obj.Media == mediaselect_str) {
    parsedData.push({
        x: parseInt(obj.Row),
        y: parseInt(obj.Column),
        label: [obj.Data, obj.Media, obj.Code]
    })
    }
});

var chart = Highcharts.chart('tray_container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'heatmap',
        width: 500,
        height: 500,            
    
    },
    title: {
        text: null
    },
    plotOptions: {
        heatmap: {
            borderColor: "black",
            paddingRight: 100
        },
    },
    series: [{
        name: null,
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: parsedData,
        dataLabels: {
            inside: true,//Show 
            enabled: true,
            useHTML: true,
            opacity: 1,
            verticalAlign:'middle',
            align: 'center',
            style: {
                textShadow: 'none',
                HcTextStroke: null,
                display: 'block'
        },
            formatter: function() {
            const label = this.point.label;
            return `${label[1]} <br/> ${label[2]} <br/> ${label[0]}`
            }
        },
    }]
});
```

Is there anything I did wrong? Thank you.

=================================================================

Updated: Solution from JMS work prefectly, but in my real case my json data was called from somewhere so this will be a function. Based on JMS's method the result was while I make selection from dropdown it counldn't find update() function since it was nested inside my function.
Sorry I'm still new in the javascript and I can't figure out how to solve it.

```
function generate_chart(data) {
// populate Media to dropdown list
$.each(data, function (index, record) {
    $('<option>', {
        value: record.Media,
        text: record.Media
    }).appendTo("#select_media");
});

// remove duplicate value from dropdown list
var optionValues =[];
$('#select_media option').each(function(){
if($.inArray(this.value, optionValues) >-1){
    $(this).remove()
}else{
    optionValues.push(this.value);
}
});

update();
function update() {
// find the maximun of x & y values by row and column
var max_x = Math.max.apply(Math, fildata.map(function(mx) {
    return mx.OutputRow;
}))
var max_y = Math.max.apply(Math, fildata.map(function(my) {
    return my.OutputColumn;
}))
console.log(max_x, max_y)

// assign x & y axis array with the maxiumn 
var x = Array(max_x).fill().map((element, index) => index)
var y = Array(max_y).fill().map((element, index) => index)


// getting drop down list value
var mediaselect = document.getElementById("select_media").value


mediaselect_str = String(mediaselect)

const parsedData = []
data.forEach(obj => {
    if (obj.Media == mediaselect_str) {
    parsedData.push({
        x: parseInt(obj.Row),
        y: parseInt(obj.Column),
        label: [obj.Data, obj.Media, obj.Code]
    })
    }
});

var chart = Highcharts.chart('tray_container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'heatmap',
        width: 500,
        height: 500,            
    
    },
    title: {
        text: null
    },
    plotOptions: {
        heatmap: {
            borderColor: "black",
            paddingRight: 100
        },
    },
    series: [{
        name: null,
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: parsedData,
        dataLabels: {
            inside: true,//Show 
            enabled: true,
            useHTML: true,
            opacity: 1,
            verticalAlign:'middle',
            align: 'center',
            style: {
                textShadow: 'none',
                HcTextStroke: null,
                display: 'block'
        },
            formatter: function() {
            const label = this.point.label;
            return `${label[1]} <br/> ${label[2]} <br/> ${label[0]}`
            }
        },
    }]
});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never subscribed to changes of the dropdown, so the data will not change.

1. Add an onchange listener on the dropdown

   ```
    <select id="select_media" onchange="update()" >
   ```
2. Put your update logic into the `function update()` function

```
function update() {
   // getting drop down list value
   var mediaselect = document.getElementById("select_media").value
   mediaselect_str = String(mediaselect)

   const parsedData = []
   data.forEach(obj => {
       if (obj.Media == mediaselect_str) {
       parsedData.push({
           x: parseInt(obj.Row),
           y: parseInt(obj.Column),
           label: [obj.Data, obj.Media, obj.Code]
       })
       }
   });

   var chart = Highcharts.chart('tray_container', {
       chart: {
           type: 'heatmap',
           width: 500,
           height: 500,            
       
       },
       title: {
           text: null
       },
       plotOptions: {
           heatmap: {
               borderColor: "black",
               paddingRight: 100
           },
       },
       series: [{
           name: null,
           borderWidth: 1,
           data: parsedData,
           dataLabels: {
               inside: true,//Show 
               enabled: true,
               useHTML: true,
               opacity: 1,
               verticalAlign:'middle',
               align: 'center',
               style: {
                   textShadow: 'none',
                   HcTextStroke: null,
                   display: 'block'
           },
               formatter: function() {
               const label = this.point.label;
               return `${label[1]} <br/> ${label[2]} <br/> ${label[0]}`
               }
           },
       }]
   });
  }
```

3. Call `update()` once yourself right at the start, to get the initial chart

See the working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ran2vz7s/3/

Comment: It's work prefectly, thank you. By the way there is still some issues within the code because my data was called as Json format and this will also be called as a "function". Based on your method the listener cannot call "function update()" function since it was nested inside my function. my function code was updated in the question.

Comment: You probably just have to move the update function outside of your original function into the global scope.

Comment: There were several variables called from inside my function the update function, so I think directly moving out the update function into global scope won't work.

Comment: Then try to also move those outside aswell, or define them again in the function.

Comment: For my system framework my JSON data wasn't loaded on the webpage first (need to set up criteria and query from somewhere depending on the condition. If I move the update function to outside it is required to load something first, but initially it didn't have any data on it and end up it will show my data didn't define yet.

Comment: I suppose if the "update function" was written on the global scope, the JS will default load this function right? Is there any way to prevent loading "update function" first until I make action on the "drop down" list?

Answer (score 0):

The update() will be good options, under is demo showing how to change chart data with select element.

```
const data = {
  data1: [
    [0, 0, 10],
    [0, 1, 19],
    [0, 2, 8],
    [0, 3, 24],
    [0, 4, 67],
    [1, 0, 92],
  ],

  data2: [
    [1, 1, 58],
    [1, 2, 78],
    [1, 3, 117],
    [1, 4, 48],
    [2, 0, 35],
    [2, 1, 15],
  ],

  data3: [
    [2, 2, 123],
    [2, 3, 64],
    [2, 4, 52],
    [3, 0, 72],
    [3, 1, 132],
    [3, 2, 114],
  ]
}


const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'heatmap'
  },
  series: [{
    data: data.data1
  }]
});

var select = document.getElementById('select');

select.addEventListener('change', function() {
  chart.series[0].update({
    data: data[this.value]
  });
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/m84f3spx/

API References:
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update

Comment: By the way is there any way to update the chart not from the data "series" but from the "attribute" section? Based on the API references from HighChart I didn't find how to call on data "attribute" (let's say data.Media from my data structure).

Comment: Alternatively you can use [Highcharts.Series#setData](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData), [example](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/series-setdata/), that attributes you mean?